# Spring Data Neo4j 4 and schema indexes for @GraphId

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

According to official SDN4 [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_index_management_in_spring_data_neo4j_4) - `In Spring Data Neo4j 4, index management concerns were removed from the mapping framework entirely`.

So how about indexes for `@GraphId` ? Is it also out of scope in SDN4 and indexes for fields annotated with `@GraphId` have to be also created manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@GraphId` currently represents the neo4j internal id on which you don't have any control.

Querying by id is the fastest lookup in neo4j btw.